# Getting QGIS "zoom to layer" to work with PostGIS data in multiple projections

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system, zoom, xml

So I have a .qgs file that contains multiple postgis layers, some in EPSG 4326 and some in EPSG 26910, with the .qgs file in 4326.  When I use the "zoom to layer" functionality on the layer in 4326, the view area zoom completely out to the entire projected globe and I get a sequence of 6 errors in the CRS Log Messages saying
`Warning Simplify transform error caught: forward transform of (inf, inf)  Error: Fallback transform failed`.

I attempted to alter the .qgs XML to find/replace instances of 'srid=4326' with 'srid=26910' but that only makes the *opposite* problem happen (layers in EPGS:26917 not working).  I have a feeling it may be related to https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34983, but not sure.

Does anyone know if there is a way to configure the .qgs file to work with layers in multiple projections, such that the "zoom to layer" functionality works across the different layers?

Comment: If the layer extents are outside the valid area of the target projection, then it is not possible to zoom to those extents. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: You can try to right click on the layer, properties, sources, update extent then go back to the info tab and check the extent. As CL said, if you have incompatible geometries, you would have to fix them first.

Comment: Thanks for the info @CL, that makes sense.  The data itself are at the right location, so I expected the zoom to layer function just to zoom to the extent of those features but I didn't consider that the underlying projections were fundamentally incompatible.

Comment: About the issue: this behavior is not related with that. About editing the definition of the CRS of the layers instances in the project file: just don't do that. Please, set the correct CRS of the layers or load them again in the project and share a screenshot with their CRS and extents (information tab in the layers properties).

Comment: What are the actual extents of the layers, in their own projection?